# How to set environment variables from sub-Makefiles to its root Makefile or my current shell?

Tags: shell, makefile

For example, my root Makefile is at `~/`, and I called a sub-Makefile at: `~/subdir/Makefile`. How can I export environment variables from the sub-Makefile globally, to the current executing shell of my root Makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [geekosaur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643977/geekosaur) noted, you can't do it directly; a child process cannot modify the environment of a parent process.

What you might be able to do is have the parent makefile include a file from the sub-directory which the makefile in the sub-directory also uses, and those settings are then, effectively, in the parent makefile.

You can't get make to export variables to your current shell at all; you'd have to have make run an interactive shell for you with the environment variables set — but that would be a very weird way of doing business.

Answer (score 2):

The environment only goes from parents to children, not the reverse.